# generating segment labels for a Tensor given a value indicating segment boundaries

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, bert-language-model, fairseq

Does anyone know of a way to generate a 'segment label' for a Tensor, given a unique value that represents segment boundaries within the Tensor?

For example, given a 1D input tensor where the value `1` represents a segment boundary,

`x = torch.Tensor([5, 4, 1, 3, 6, 2])`

the resulting segment label Tensor should have the same shape with values representing the two segments:

`segment_label = torch.Tensor([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])`

Likewise, for a batch of inputs, e.g. batch size = 3,

```
x = torch.Tensor([
    [5, 4, 1, 3, 6, 2],
    [9, 4, 5, 1, 8, 10],
    [10, 1, 5, 4, 8, 9]
    ])
```

the resulting segment label Tensor (using `1` as the segment separator) should look something like this:

```
segment_label = torch.Tensor([
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    ])
```

**Context**: I'm currently working with Fairseq's Transformer implementation in PyTorch for a seq2seq NLP task. I am looking for a way to incorporate BERT-like segment embeddings in Transformer during the encoder's forward pass, rather than modifying an exisiting dataset used for translation tasks such as `language_pair_dataset`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`torch.cumsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cumsum.html#torch.cumsum) to pull the trick:

```py
mask = (x == 1).to(x)  # mask with only the boundaries
segment_label = mask.cumsum(dim=-1) - mask + 1
```

Results with the desired `segment_label`.

Comment: Thanks Shai! This is a neat solution. I got it working with a for-loop approach in the meantime but `.cumsum()` is much faster.